# Chips vs wafers vs transistors

Tags: transistors, computer-architecture

Sorry to ask such a trivial question but I am a non-engineering student currently writing an essay on Moore's law and I can't seem to find how the items in my title relate.  An in-depth description of each item would be greatly appreciated!  Also if you could please breakdown technical terms, that would be very helpful.  Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit ? **Chips** are the same as **Integrated Circuits** (IC). **ICs** are made on from a thin disc of silicon called a **Wafer**. ICs contain small circuits made of **transistors**.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the role of the wafer is on the chip?  I have a good understanding of what a transistor does but not the wafer part.

Comment: @CheekyNandose Quoting wikipedia article on Wafer "A wafer, also called a slice or substrate,[1] is a thin slice of semiconductor material, such as a crystalline silicon, used in electronics for the fabrication of integrated circuits and..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer_(electronics)

Comment: To my understanding, wafers cover the surface of the pcb.  This makes it so that the pcb has semi conductive properties for electricity to flow through.  Transistors are then laid on the pcb?

Comment: *To my understanding, wafers cover the surface of the pcb* **That is not true !** A PCB has conductive tracks made of copper. Components like transistors, chips, capacitors and resistors are then soldered onto the PCB.

Comment: @CheekyNandose No you got it confused. You can get transistors and along with other components, lay them out on a PCB with, which is a non-conductive board covered with a layer of copper that makes the connections. 
A lot of transistors and other components can be miniaturised and built in a single **chip**. These **chips** are made on a silicon disk called **wafer**. The wafer is cut into individual chips at the production facility.

Comment: There is a clear distinction between PCBs and chips/wafers. A PCB is something you would find in a phone. On that PCB are chips and transistors. Those chips and transistors are the **semiconductors**. Those semiconductors are fabricated on wafers (thin silicon disks). As a normal person you will never encounter a wafer. Wafers are sawn into individual chips or transistors. A wafer might contain 1000 individual and identical chips or 10000 individual and identical transistors.

Answer (score 13):

- **WAFER** A thin slice of silicon crystal. Typically ~1mm thick and 200-300mm in diameter. (The size of a medium to large pizza.) We put wafers through hundreds of processing steps to produce....
- **CHIPS** or Integrated Circuits.  A small rectangular section of the wafer that contains a complete circuit which is used to make computers, phones, etc. Each chip or IC contains thousands, millions or billions of....
- **TRANSISTORS** which are the basic building-block of modern integrated circuits. Modern transistors are much smaller than a human hair and can only be seen under a strong microscope. This photo shows a wafer with hundreds of chips before being sliced apart.  A few packaged ICs are sitting on top of the wafer.

[image]

When the wafer processing is completed. The individual chips are cut out of the wafer and individually packaged. Then these IC packages are soldered onto....

- **PCB** or Printed Circuit Board is a thin piece of fiberglass with copper patterns etched on both sides. This photo shows a typical PC board (green) with the copper traces (wires) and several different kinds of electronic components (including integrated circuits) soldered onto the board

[image]

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5paWn7bFg4
PDF: http://download.intel.com/newsroom/kits/chipmaking/pdfs/Sand-to-Silicon_32nm-Version.pdf

Comment: With gate widths down to single-digit nanometers today, you haven't been able to see transistors with an ordinary light microscope for quite a few years by now :) still an excellent answer

Comment: But I don't fully agree on your usage of chip / IC - the integrated circuit, to me, integrates the contacting etc, so whereas you usually don't buy a single die (the rectangular cut of the wafer), you can find ICs in every distributor's stock

Comment: ... which of course breaks down with wire-to-board packaging and chip-scale-packages, but to me, an IC is "the smallest indivisible unit containing circuity that is still usable for constructing a device. So I'd say "all chips are dies cut from a wafer, but not all ICs are just chips"

Comment: Certainly every detail of this answer is oversimplified and will not stand up to rigorous analysis. The OP is non-technical and this is a broad-brush attempt to clear up basic terminology.

Comment: Richard, fair and good point!